# Let any Microsoft account login to a PC

Tags: windows-10

We have a small company with 10 PC/laptops - no Active directory domain or anything.

Say a computer breaks down; I'd like to set all the PCs so that someone can login to any of them with their Microsoft Account without having to add the account beforehand.

Is this possible?

Comment: "Is this possible?" - No

Comment: Set up a network server and use that for security. https://www.bytestart.co.uk/how-to-set-up-a-small-network-without-buying-a-server.html